# Destructure variable in return statement in JavaScript

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am writing test with Jest and React Testing Library. Came across such a code online, that I will later call in each of my test to load variables.

```
const setup = () => {
    const component = render(<Form getApi={getApi} />);
    const submitButton = screen.getByRole('button', { name: 'send' });
    const inputField = screen.getByRole('textbox');

    return {
        input,
        submitBtn,
        ...component
    }
}
```

My question is: why is the component destructured in return statement? And how should I import it in my test?
example:

```
describe('<Auth />', () => {
    test('should render login field and password field', () => {
        setup();
});
```

Comment: There is no destructuring here, it's a standard object literal.

Answer (score 2):

While they both use `...`, that's actually the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), not [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). It's making a shallow copy of `component` into a new object. So all the properties on the `component` object will now also be properties on the new object. It's similar to doing:

```
const newObj = { 
  input,
  submitBtn,
}
newObj.queryByLabelText = component.queryByLabelText;
newObj.getByLabelText = component.getByLabelText;
// ... etc for all properties
return newObj
```

Or:

```
return Object.assign({ input, submitBtn }, component);
```

---

You'll use it like this:

```
test('should render login field and password field', () => {
  const value = setup();
  // do stuff with value.input, value.submitBtn, value.queryByLabelText, value.getByLabelText, etc
});
```

Or:

```
test('should render login field and password field', () => {
  const { input, submitBtn, queryByLabelText, getByLabelText } = setup();
  // etc
});
```